# .htaccess redirect with ignore query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect without looking at the query string, and my redirect result no need append the query string as well, so I add a `?` at the end of the RewriteRule.

I tried the following syntax, but the outcome just close to it.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .* [NC]
RewriteRule ^exd\.asp$ http://www.example.com/index.php?r=p/consumer? [R=301,L]
```

and also, i tried to escape the first `?`, which I need it, but still the same outcome.

```
RewriteRule ^exd\.asp$ http://www.example.com/index.php\?r=p/consumer? [R=301,L]
```

Outcome:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?r=p/consumer%3f
```

I want to get ride of the `%3f`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to append a `?` at the end if you already have a query string in your target. Just do this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .* [NC]
RewriteRule ^exd\.asp$ http://www.example.com/index.php?r=p/consumer [R=301,L]
```

By default, query strings get appended, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^foo$ /bar [L]
```

You request `/foo?blah` and you get `/bar?blah`

However, if you have a `?` in your target, query strings won't get appended unless you have the `QSA`, so:

```
RewriteRule ^foo1$ /bar? [L]
RewriteRule ^foo2$ /bar?q=2 [L]
```

You request `/foo1?blah` and you get `/bar`, you request `/foo2?blah` and you get `/bar?q=2`. If you include a `QSA` in the rewrite flags, then `&blah` gets appended to the end.

Comment: hi Jon Lin, I actually tried without put a ? at the end, I still get the result http://www.example.com/index.php?r=p/consumer%3f , is it anyting wrong in RewriteCond ?

Comment: @Shiro there is no way a `%3f` gets stuck in at the end unless there's another rule that does that or you're browser cache needs to be cleared.